# Font Embedding Causes Scrambled Characters When Making PDF from Word or Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, pdf, fonts, adobe-acrobat

I have a peculiar issue where if I File + Print and Choose PDF as the Printer, I get scrambled up text, the PDF doesn't embed nor do I get errors it couldn't embed fonts.  If I choose File + Make PDF, it generally doesn't fail, though it does at times.

[image: File Print Method]  [image: File Adobe PDF]

If I were to do a test in InDesign, it has no issues upon Exporting the PDF, nor when I go to Find Font, do I see any restrictions on the font listed.

Has this issue been seen before and if so how do I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the left-hand screenshot snippet taken on the same system that the PDF was created on?

Comment: Yes both were generated through Word 2016 using Adobe Acrobat 2017 Standard.

Comment: In acrobat, have you checked the font embedding status in the document properties (possibly File menu > Properties) for inconsistencies between the indesign export and the word export? Also, have you tried using the PDF printer instead of the Word plugin?

Comment: The scrambled up one is what happens when I do File > Print and choose Adobe Acrobat as the printer.  The one on the right is what happens when I try to print via Save as Adobe Acrobat from the File menu in Word.  The same thing is occurring in Excel when I use the same fonts.  I also cleared out the Font Cache.  I haven't tried yet as a different user, however.

Comment: What's also interesting, some of the fonts are not listed when I go to Adobe menu and visit Preferences.  Only if I print High Quality does the File Save PDF even work, or at least more fonts than I could before.

Comment: Through the printer driver, usually you would uncheck "do not embed" in the printer properties. But even so, if they are not embedded they ought still display on the same system. Perhaps these fonts are have a system-name difference outside of office and also are not being embedded.

Comment: What's weird, I changed it to high quality print and the second row, the text is now displaced in the font (properties shows the font has been embedded), but the text is still a random string.  The first row is also random text, not the same string, but in Courier, the penultimate row is the correct text, though kerning is off and also in courier.